# Xcode autosynthesized properties causing errors

Tags: xcode, properties, xcode4.5

Xcode has issues about `Autosynthesized property 'ViewController'` and similary about `'window'` and tells me the properties are declared in BSAppDelegate.h. I don't know how to fix this even though several people here have tried to explain the underscore issue. When I omit any of the lines below which mention ViewController or window, my app will not compile.

```
//
//  BSAppDelegate.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class BSViewController;

@interface BSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    UIWindow *window;
    BSViewController *viewController;
}


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) BSViewController *viewController;

@end
```

Comment: When you say "Xcode has issues ...", please include a line of code that fails and the exact message Xcode produces for it.

Comment: Autosynthesized properties `window` and `viewController` have auto-created iVars `_window` and `_viewController`. You are getting confused because you have separately declared iVars manually without underscores, these refer to different entities than your `window` and `viewController` properties unless you manually @synthesize. Where exactly is Xcode complaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare properties, you don't need to also declare the same variables in the instance variables section. In other words, this should be fine:

```
@interface BSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) BSViewController *viewController;

@end
```

If your app fails to compile like this, do you have a second @interface section and/or do you have @synthesize statements in the implementation file? As of Xcode 4.4 you don't need the @synthesize statements anymore, but if you don't explicitly synthesize the properties then Xcode will synthesize them with a preceding underscore (_window or _viewController). Here's a link with more information: [Automatic Property Synthesis With Xcode 4.4](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html).